# Azure active directory infinite redirect loop

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have 2 azure accounts:

1. my personal account
2. my work account

---

1. I created app registration on **PERSONAL** account:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-option-2-use-an-existing-registration-created-separately

2. I created **python** web app  (with default microsoft hello screen, no code) on WORK account and registered authentication with  Microsoft AD. (with client ID and secret form personal account), also with  return URL,  (tried web and single page)

Now, when I enter web app URL I got redirected on login.microsoft,...  but here comes problem, after I login (with my personal account) application will request me again which account I want, and again and again ang again,... infinite loop.

Do someone has similar experience?

I checked something on stackoverflow, but there are some libs (really old) in c# which handles it, but I don't have c# application and even I have no code on server. This should be no problem, because you can also deploy static web app via ftp on web app, and like half of year ago it was working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I didn't copied SECRET VALUE, but I copied SECRET KEY, I figured out this thanks to this mdal example project, which warned me about invalid secret:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there any way someone could answer this from the info you provide in your question? Please do not self-answer such question, which is extremely unlikely to be of any help for others in the future; better delete the thread altogether.

Comment: Actually, this was exactly my issue when I ran into this problem. While I agree that it could be worded much better, when you're working in the context, it does make sense. +1

Comment: Yeah, chrome that time had bug, when you copied link it copied like from history step before, so provided link was bad sorry for miss-info.  Also in repository of Microsoft was bug, the second part of answer was way how to fix it....